# MS access: Export query output to excel and auto create Pie Chart in excel

Tags: sql

Folks,

i want to generate ( or trigger) query output from MS Access to MS Excel.

I want either embed code within SQL query which generates .xls or write external code.

Now i am generating report using "export" option but i want to automate export.

-Vijay

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. If you export csv data to an xls, excel will interpret it fine.

http://www.databasedev.co.uk/exporting-data-with-vba.html